# Did I install cabal correctly?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, happy, alex

Hi I've just updated cabal to the latest version by the command

```
cabal update
```

and

```
cabal install cabal-install
```

Then it returns

```
Installed cabal-install-1.22.2.0
Updating documentation index /MyPath
```

I want to use alex and happy. Sorry I'm very new to it.. When I tried to issue alex in ghci by the line

```
alex wordcount.x
```

It returns

```
Not in scope: ‘alex’
Perhaps you meant ‘lex’ (imported from Prelude)
```

I searched online for this and I found a webpage saying that I should first check the version of them by

```
 cabal configure -v | grep -e alex -e happy
```

But I got this line

```
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you `cabal install alex` ?

Comment: @Sibi Oops... Have to say I didn't... Sorry this question is so dumb..

Comment: That's fine. Happens with everyone. :)

Comment: @Sibi Thank you so much!! Sorry quite new to Haskell and everything..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you install `cabal` you can *install other packages*.

So, to install the Alex package, you'll do `cabal install alex`. Then I see that you tried to invoke Alex in GHCi, but that's not correct, since `alex` is a program. You have to invoke it from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Solved everything :D

Comment: @YiyueWang Happy to be of help.